# SQL count when value = 1

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a select on two tables with this:

```
SELECT m.torneio, m.deck, m.top, m.lugar, sum( m.quantidade ) AS quantidade, m.formato AS formato, q.quantidade AS qtorneio, t.season AS season, sum( m.top ) AS totaltops, count( m.lugar = '1' ) AS venceu
FROM `metagame` AS m, quantidade AS q, torneios AS t
WHERE m.torneio = t.nome
AND m.torneio = q.nome
GROUP BY m.deck
```

My problem is that venceu is counting all instances instead of only the ones when lugar = 1. Why is that?

tried with sum() too with no good results too. How can i fix this?

Comment: Do you mean, `where m.lugar = '1'`

Comment: you tried `sum(case when m.lugar = '1' then 1 else 0 end)`?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch that is it!! forgot to use the case, kind of rusty in sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised that count( m.lugar = '1' ) syntaxs but it does and returns the sames as count(*). You should probably change it to sum(case when lugar = 1 else 0 end) as venceu. You should also look closely at the group by to be sure it works as you expect (i suspect not).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you can use this:

```
sum(case when m.lugar = '1' then 1 else 0 end)
```

or you can try `having` clause

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
GROUP BY column_name(s)
HAVING condition
ORDER BY column_name(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

`count(x)` does not accept an expression.

It's only counting how many times `x` is returned.

What you should do is check if `m.lugar` is `1` and yes add one to the counter else do nothing.

Inline checks can be done like so:

```
case when m.lugar = '1' then 1 else 0 end
```

Then add all the one you gets :

```
sum(case when m.lugar = '1' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Your final query should look like this:

```
SELECT 
    m.torneio, 
    m.deck, 
    m.top, 
    m.lugar, 
    sum( m.quantidade ) AS quantidade, 
    m.formato AS formato, 
    q.quantidade AS qtorneio, 
    t.season AS season, 
    sum( m.top ) AS totaltops, 
    sum(case when m.lugar = '1' then 1 else 0 end) AS venceu
FROM 
    `metagame` AS m, 
    quantidade AS q, 
    torneios AS t
WHERE 
    m.torneio = t.nome
    AND m.torneio = q.nome
GROUP BY 
    m.deck
```